# How to get all results at once?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

What am I doing wrong? It shows KeyError: 'One'?  I want to have output in a list displaying:

```
title:""
price:""
rating:""
```

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from random import choice

url = r.get("https://books.toscrape.com/")
resp = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,"html.parser")

def clean_price(price):
   return float (re.sub("[^0-9.]", " ", price))

def map_rating(rating):
 rating_map = {
    "one": 1,
    "Two": 2,
    "Three": 3,
    "Four": 4,
    "Five": 5
 }
 return rating_map[rating]

def extract_book_data (book_tag):
 title = book_tag.find("h3").find("a")["title"]
 price = book_tag.find("p",attrs={"class":"price_color"}).get_text()
 rating = book_tag.find("p",attrs={"class":"star-rating"})["class"][-1]
 return {
    "title": title,
    "price": clean_price(price),
    "rating": map_rating(rating)
 }
book_tags = soup.find_all("article", attrs={"class":"product_pod"})
book_data = [extract_book_data(book_tag) for book_tag in book_tags]

 print(book_data)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: It's a typo. You want to change the key `"one"` to `"One"` inside `rating_map`.

Comment: @ouroboros1 Yes. That was the problem and finally it's solved thank you so much i have started recently and i was stucked for days i was trying every solution and from here i will keep in mind for such things.

Comment: You're welcome. One of the most important things is to invest in understanding what a `full error traceback` is telling you. In your case, it will have ended by saying that it failed to execute `return rating_map[rating]`, namely because "One" (stored inside `rating`) does not exist as a `key` in the dictionary `rating_map` (`KeyError: 'One'`). When you look at this dict, indeed, you can see right away that there's a typo. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

> *It's a typo. You want to change the key `"one"` to `"One"` inside `rating_map`.*
>
> -- [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76545668/how-to-get-all-results-at-once#comment134962116_76545668) by [ouroboros1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18470692/ouroboros1)

Answer (score 0):

The `print(book_data)` statement was indented incorrectly. It should be aligned with the previous line `book_data = [extract_book_data(book_tag) for book_tag in book_tags]`.

Your code, will be:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from random import choice

url = r.get("https://books.toscrape.com/")
resp = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")

def clean_price(price):
    return float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", " ", price))

def map_rating(rating):
    rating_map = {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2,
        "three": 3,
        "four": 4,
        "five": 5
    }
    return rating_map[rating.lower()]

def extract_book_data(book_tag):
    title = book_tag.find("h3").find("a")["title"]
    price = book_tag.find("p", attrs={"class": "price_color"}).get_text()
    rating = book_tag.find("p", attrs={"class": "star-rating"})["class"][-1]
    return {
        "title": title,
        "price": clean_price(price),
        "rating": map_rating(rating)
    }

book_tags = soup.find_all("article", attrs={"class": "product_pod"})
book_data = [extract_book_data(book_tag) for book_tag in book_tags]

print(book_data)
```

Please note that in the `map_rating` function, the rating is converted to lowercase using `rating.lower()` to handle case sensitivity.